# Javascript XML http request can not open RSS file from server, XML status = 0

Tags: javascript, xml, rss, xmlhttprequest, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an RSS feed using javascript, and I recently ran into a problem opening an XML file from both localhost and web server (I always access my local files using http:// keyword all the time when I work on localhost). I received XML status 0 instead of status 200 (established) in all browser. The problem only occurs when I try to open an XML file hosted on a server. Here is what I have :

```
if(window.ActiveXObject)//IE
    xml_req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
else if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    xml_req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else alert('no ajax support');

xml_req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://www.something.net/rss.xml";
xml_req.open("GET", url, true);

xml_req.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xml_req.readyState == 4){
        if(xml_req.status == 200){
            if(xml_req.responseText != null)
                .....//DO STUFF
            else{
                alert("Error");
                return false;
            }
        }
        else{
                  //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS,STATUS=0 INSTEAD OF 200
               alert("XML Status = " + xml_req.status + xml_req.statusText);}
    }
}
```

Everything works fine when I open an XML local file that is not hosted on the server. For instance, the code below opens the rss file within the localhost just fine :

```
var url = "rssLocalhost.xml";
xml_req.open("GET", url, true);
```

Please help! Would appreciate any suggestions from anybody out there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [can't make requests to other sites](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). You either need to proxy the data through your own server, or use a JSON-P data source.

Comment: It's really helpful, thanks for the answer. So if I try to consume the data from JSON-P data source, is the data going to be in raw XML or do I have to change some of the codes in my parser? (since my parser currently only parses XML files)

Comment: If you have a JSON-P datasource then it will be in JSON-P, not XML.

Comment: yeah looks like it would've been much easier had I used JSONP, but it was a good experience for me though :)